# Автообновление QListView

Tags: python, pyqt5

В QListView отображается сетевой каталог. Каким образом сделать автообновление этого списка при изменении структуры файлов в сетевом каталоге ? На данный момент данный список обновляется при повторном открытии формы с QListView.

Проверил на локальном каталоге - QListView сразу обновляет список при изменении каталога (удалении или добавлении файла) без добавления каких-либо дополнительный действий.

Причем если подключить данную шару как сетевой диск - автообновление работает.

А вот если указывать путь в виде `\\IP\share` - не работает.

Comment: А через какую модель отображаете?

Comment: QFileSystemModel